# How to use :observer.start with my app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to inspect my app using `:observer.start`, I tried interactive elixir console:

```
iex -S mix
```

of course, this would load all the dependencies and start the app, then I can start the observer using: `:observer.start`

but I've noticed that I can't browser into the app using the browser, ex: `localhost:4000`

I can only browse into the app if I started it using: `mix phoenix.server`

The question is, how can I browse into the app when its started as `iex -S mix` ?

**EDIT**

What are all those processes? I just started the app without doing anything?
[image]

I've checked one of them:
[image]
but I don't know what is that process for?

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the following to start both an interactive shell and the phoenix server.

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please check the EDIT above?

Comment: Those processes are the ranch acceptors. There should be 100 of them. They are defined in your cowboy config. You configure it inside the http: [...] for your endpoint. Something like `http: [num_acceptors: 10]`

Comment: So, what do they do actually?